# How to open new PDF document with hyperref that doesn't fit the entire screen?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

In my PDF document I use `hyperref` package to link to external PDF documents. Whenever I use such a link the external PDF document opens on the entire screen. Is there a way to tell `hyperref` to open a pdf document in a size that doesn't fit the screen?

I tried this setting:

```
\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow=true,pdffitwindow=false}
```

but that didn't do the trick. Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: No, because the opened PDF, not the opening one, defines how it will be scaled in the viewer initially.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. I think I meant how to control scaling of the viewer on the screen instead how to control scaling of the pdf in the viewer.

Comment: Ah I see. I think this is very specific to the PDF viewer. Maybe it can be adjusted in its preferences.

Comment: I like to use [pdfstartview=FitH] and \href[pdfnewwindow].